# How to copy old folder to new folder and rename files in the new folder

Tags: c#

The old folder name is 'dat' and all the files under 'dat' folder are prefixed with the folder name, i.e 'dat'.

Example:

dat/dat_x1.dat
dat/dat_b1.dat
etc

I would like to create a new folder, say 'datNew' and add all the files of 'dat' folder into 'datNew' folder. However, this time, the prefix of the files in the 'datNew' folder takes the new folder name 'datNew'. Then, it will give the following:

datNew/datNew_xt.dat
datNew/datNew_b1.dat
etc

I use the following colde to copy but am unable to search the prefix in the files and replace them with the new prefix

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(dat, fName), Path.Combine(datNew, fName))
```

How can I rename the prefix of the files in the new folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should get a folder object, and then iterate through each of the file objects within it. For each one, get the old file name, and then determine the new file name. Still in the for each, copy from old to new. Your resulting code would be:

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(dat, fName), Path.Combine(datNew, fNameNew))
```

To determine the new prefix, something like:

```
var newFilename = fName.Replace(dat, datNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will do the job:

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(dat, fName), Path.Combine(datNew, fName.Replace(dat,dataNew)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple modification resolved my problem

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(dat, fName), Path.Combine(datNew, Replace(fName, "old-prefix", "new-prefix")))
```